# How to use syntax record declaration with members

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying generate c# 9 record using roslyn. but, having problem to create a simple record.

What i'm trying to achieve is

```
public record Student(string FirstName, string LastName);
```

I created.

```
var recordDeclaration = SyntaxFactory.RecordDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.RecordKeyword), "Student");
        recordDeclaration = recordDeclaration.AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword));
```

Then, not sure how to addd members to it.

Comment: Members or constructor parameters? What you've got now is parameters, so `.WithParameterList` should do the trick (members, of course, is `.WithMembers`).

Comment: i think it's properties of student record.